# javascript Execution order when using appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

I'm using "createContextualFragment" to parse html string and appending it to an iframe like this:

```
let DocumentFragmentDom = this.Document.createRange().createContextualFragment(this.Html);
IframeDocument.body.appendChild(DocumentFragmentDom);
```

everything is working as it should except 2 js tags , the first one declare a function and the second one is calling it (the first one is above the second).
if i'm using document.write everything is working perfectly but when i'm using the above method (via appendchild) i'm getting :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MyFunc is not defined
```

i think thats because the second js tag is parsed and executed before the first one even if the first is above the second, for example:

```
<script id ="firstjs">//function declaration </script>
<script id = "secondjs">//function call </script>
```

so i'm guessing that when i use appendchild i'm actually messing the execution  order, any ideas?

Comment: Do your scripts in `firstjs` and `secondjs` use an event to execute their code? somthing like `window.onload` or jQuery's `$(document).ready`?

Comment: @Kaddath the scripts are third party scripts and are minified so it's quite complicated to tell, i tried using a while loop to append each node at a time but i get the same problem , i think i can also try to use addeventlistener for the load event but thats quite complicated to implement